# Insert into command inserts nothing, but the select statement returns all the elements needed

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a SQL table called `Listing` which is representing houses that have been rented. The table has a primary key `id` and another column called `amenities` with the things each house had to offer. The amenities of each house are separated from each other with a comma. For example TV, Internet, Bathroom.

I used the following commands to create a table called Amenity with all the unique different amenities offered and a SERIAL number for each amenity.

```
CREATE TABLE Amenity 
AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         regexp_split_to_table(amenities,',') 
     FROM Listing);

ALTER TABLE Amenity
RENAME regexp_split_to_table to amenity_name;

ALTER TABLE Amenity ADD COLUMN amenity_id SERIAL;
ALTER TABLE Amenity ADD PRIMARY KEY(amenity_id);
```

I now have to connect my two tables which have a many-to-many relationship by using a new table which will be something like this:

Table **HOUSE_AMENITIES**

```
+----------+------------+
| house_id | amenity_id |
+----------+------------+
|    1     |      1     |
|    2     |      1     |
|    2     |      2     |
|    2     |      3     |
+----------+------------+
```

So I used the following code and then I was planning to delete the column `am_name` from `Amenity_connect_to_Listing`.

```
CREATE TABLE Amenity_connect_to_Listing 
AS
    (SELECT regexp_split_to_table(amenities, ','), id 
     FROM Listing);

ALTER TABLE Amenity_connect_to_Listing
RENAME COLUMN id TO listing_id;

ALTER TABLE Amenity_connect_to_Listing
RENAME COLUMN regexp_split_to_table TO am_name;

ALTER TABLE Amenity_connect_to_Listing
ADD COLUMN amen_id int;

INSERT INTO Amenity_connect_to_Listing(amen_id) 
(SELECT amenity_id FROM Amenity
JOIN Amenity_connect_to_Listing ON Amenity_connect_to_Listing.am_name like Amenity.amenity_name);
```

My problem here is that the last command outputs `INSERT 0 172123` which means that although 172123 items where selected, none was inserted to the table `Amenity_connect_to_Listing` and I don't know neither why this happened nor how to fix it. I have checked other questions with a somewhat similar problem but none of them used `JOIN` and none of the other answers seemed to work in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Run the query for the insert without the insert statement.
You are getting no updates as either

- your inner join to amenity_connect_to_listing is wrong
- there are no related records in amenity_connect_to_listing

Once the query is returning what you want, add the insert statement back in.
I suspect that rather than

```
like Amenity.amenity_name
```

you need

```
like '%' + Amenity.amenity_name + '%'
```

Comment: If you mean to run `SELECT amenity_id FROM Amenity
JOIN Amenity_connect_to_Listing ON Amenity_connect_to_Listing.am_name like Amenity.amenity_name;`, I tried and it gave me the 172123 numbers it should give